# Don't fire RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a list in and relaycommand viewmodel,

```
private List<PurchaseInvoiceDetail> detailList = new List<PurchaseInvoiceDetail>();
public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
   ICollectionView _detailCollection;

    public ICollectionView DetailCollection
    {
        get { return _detailCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _detailCollection)
            {
                _detailCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DetailCollection");
            }
        }
    }
```

when i use DetailCollection in constructor,dont fire relaycommand.

```
public PurchaseInvoiceDetailViewModel(PurchaseInvoice item)
 {
  if (item != null)
   {
    Number = item.Number;
    CustomerId = item.CustomerId;
    Date = new PersianDate((DateTime)item.Date);
    _purchaseInvoice = item.Id;
    detailList = _db.PurchaseInvoiceDetails.Where(m => m.PurchaseInvoiceId == item.Id).ToList();
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(detailList).Refresh();
    DetailCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(detailList);
   }
   AddCommand=new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
              var goods = _db.Goods.Find(GoodsId);
                detailList.Add(new PurchaseInvoiceDetail(){GoodsId = GoodsId,Goods = goods,Count = Count,Price = Price,Id=0,PurchaseInvoiceId = 0});
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(detailList).Refresh();
                DetailCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(detailList);

        });
  }
```

but when i comment DetailCollection ,it work ok..

in view

```
 <Button Margin="0 0 5 0 " Width="90" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" 
   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"  >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="Plus" />
    <TextBlock >َAdd</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
 </Button>
 <DataGrid  CanUserDeleteRows="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}"  Name="ListView" 
 IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1"    Height="200"  Margin="0"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailCollection}" 
            >
     <DataGrid  CanUserDeleteRows="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}"  Name="ListView" 
                       IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       BorderThickness="1"    Height="200"  Margin="0"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailCollection}" 
            >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100"
                                         Header="کد کالا" Binding="{Binding Path=Goods.Code}"/>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام کالا" Binding="{Binding Path=Goods.Name}" Width="200"/>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Count}" Width="150"
                                        dataGridFilterLibrary:DataGridColumnExtensions.IsCaseSensitiveSearch="True"
                                        Header="تعداد"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="قیمت" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding 
                        Key="Delete"
                        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ListView}"/>

                </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You might want to show the xaml so we can see the bindings.

Comment: Also, detaillist isn't observablecollection, so when you set it again in the constructor, the UI might not get notified of the change.

Comment: @KevinCook  plz see my edit.

Comment: You aren't creating columns in your datagrid, and autogenerate columns is false, am I missing something here?

Comment: No, I add columns.. plz see my edit

Comment: Do you raise property change notification for `DetailCollection` property?

Comment: yes, plz see my edit